# Como replicar atualização do master para os branches no Team Foundation Server?

Tags: team-foundation-server, branch

Estou trabalhando em um projeto que possui 3 *branches*. Após algum tempo a equipe viu a necessidade de alterar o tratamento de erro, que é comum entre os 3 *branches*. Existe alguma forma de alterar o master e replicar essa alteração para os *branches*?

Answer (score 3):

Existe sim. Utilize o comando Merge de produção para os branches.
Esse artigo dá uma ajuda de como organizar seus branches.
http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

Comment: Uma ótima referência o git-flow, uso no trabalho (equipe com ~10 pessoas) e também aplico em parte nos meus projetos pessoais/exploratórios/experimentais

Answer (score 2):

Consegui!

Basta efetuar um merge do master para o branch, e existe a opção de enviar somente as alterações. :D